# Capture a group when negative look-ahead exists in it

Tags: regex

I would like to capture a group but only when a specified string is not in it (2 options).

Here is where I am: `/src=\"([^"](?!js|pdf))*\"/`

This is what I want:

```
<img src="/Storage/shot.png"/>  
=>  /Storage/shot.png

<script src="/whatever/file.js">  
=>  (Nothing here)
```

But in practice I am only getting the last letter of the group captured.
How do I fix this?

See it here: https://regex101.com/r/M9szpw/2

Comment: `src="(?![^"]*(?:js|pdf)")([^"]*)"`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Works! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `([^"](?!js|pdf))*` in your pattern is a [repeated capturing group](https://www.regular-expressions.info/captureall.html). It matches a single char other than `"` (with `[^"]`) that is not immediately followed with `js` or `pdf` (see `(?!js|pdf)` lookahead), and captures zero or more of these chars each time re-writing the group value in the group memory buffer.

You may use

```
src="(?![^"]*(?:js|pdf)")([^"]*)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/fGYGFw/1)

**Details**

- `src="` - a literal `src="` string
- `(?![^"]*(?:js|pdf)")` - negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there are 0+ chars other than `"` followed with `js` or `pdf` and then `"` char
- `([^"]*)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars other than `"`
- `"`  - a `"` char.